# Difference between replace entire node and replace node contents in OSB

Tags: osb

I have recently started using OSB and i came across the feature "replace entire node or replace node contents". Could anyone help me in listing out the difference between the two with examples.
This is a very basic question but i just started learning osb and wanted to get this right.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers..

Answer (score 4):

OK, let's assume you have a variable, `$body`. Your proxy has done some stuff, and already has $body set, and you want to run it through an xquery transform before you return it.

$body will be something like

```
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="etc">
  <ns0:response xmlns:ns0="etc2">
    <ns0:item>
      <!-- etc etc -->
    </ns0:item>
  </ns0:response>
</soap:Body>
```

If you replace the entire node, you must replace it with a `<soap:Body>`. (I mean, you *could* replace it with something different, but you'll encounter an error somewhere because OSB expects $body to be a certain type)

If you replace the node contents, you may replace it with anything: perhaps a transformed `<ns0:response>`, but it's common to replace it with totally different elements. Either way, the `<soap:Body>` element is unaffected, and all the insides are scooped out and replaced.

Most of the time, you'll replace node contents of $body rather than replacing the entire node, but if it's a variable you've created yourself, it could go either way depending on what you want.