# Weblogic 11g: BEA-382513: OSB Replace action failed updating variable "body": {err}FORG0005: expected exactly one item, got 0 items

Tags: java, user-interface, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

Did someone had this error and can advise how to fix it?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>BEA-382513: OSB Replace action failed updating variable "body": {err}FORG0005: expected exactly one item, got 0 items</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
                    <con:errorCode>BEA-382513</con:errorCode>
                    <con:reason>OSB Replace action failed updating variable "body": {err}FORG0005: expected exactly one item, got 0 items</con:reason>
                    <con:location>
                        <con:path>request-pipeline</con:path>
                        <con:error-handler>true</con:error-handler>
                    </con:location>
                </con:fault>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I looked in Internet but couldn't find any helpfull information about this.

Comment: If you found this answer correct, please accept this as the correct answer. It will help others who are looking answer to the similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of selecting 'Replace entire node', select 'Replace node contents'. By choosing 'Replace entire node', you're replacing your body tag with some other node. Selecting 'Replace node contents' will replace the body node contents and not the entire body tag.
For more information, please refer [Difference between replace entire node and replace node contents in OSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226354/difference-between-replace-entire-node-and-replace-node-contents-in-osb)